# Correct way to implement drill-down tags in vue with vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am using a v-chip-group with v-chips to represent a tag cloud for records in my database.  I have an object array with records that look something like { key:'device', count:100}.  A record could have multiple tags, so as you click on a tag, a new query is made that filters on that tag, the result will then have a new tag cloud with a subset of the previous.

It looks something like this:

tag1 (1000), tag2 (100), tag3 (100)

When you click on tag1 you end up with:

tag1 (1000), tag3 (15) (no tag2 because there is no overlap between tag1 and tag2).

Here is the relevant template code:

```
    <v-chip-group v-model="selectedTag" multiple @change="refresh">
      <v-chip v-for="tag in tags" :key="tag.key" active-class="primary">
        <v-avatar left class="grey">{{ tag.count }}</v-avatar>
        {{ tag.key }}
      </v-chip>
    </v-chip-group>
```

The problem I have is that in the typescript I do something like this:

```
refresh() {
  // get simple array of tag strings
  const selectedTags = this.selectedTag.map((value: any) => {
    if (this.tags && this.tags[value]) {
      return this.tags[value].key
    } else {
      return null
    }
  }).filter((value: any) => {
    return value != null
  })

  Promise.all([
    ...
    ApiCall('GET', 'tags', {limit: 1000, tags: selectedTags}),
    ...
  ).then((values) => {
    // decode response from server into new tags
    this.tags = values[2].series['0'].values.map((item: any) => {
      return {key: item.bucket, count: item.doc_count}
    })
    const newTags: number[] = []
    this.tags.forEach((tag, index) => {
      // find the new index of the previously selected tags and save them
      if (selectedTags.find(st => {
        return st === tag.key
      })) {
        newTags.push(index)
      }
    })
    // update selectedTag with the new value
    this.$set(this, 'selectedTag', newTags)
    // did not work this.selectedTag = newTags
  })
}
```

What I'm seeing is that when I click a chip, it correctly fires the @change event and calls refresh, but then when the refresh finishes, I see an additional refresh get called with an empty selectedTag, which clears my filters and recalls the above functionality.

Is there a way to get @change to fire when a chip is changed, but not fire (or filter it out) when the event is generated by changing the data referenced by v-model?